# Multicolumn keys in Entity Framework Code First with eager loading

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, many-to-many, dbcontext

I use Entity Framework, and I have a many-to-many relationship in the database between Users and Boxes, like this:

```
public class HistoryEntry
{
    public int BoxId { get; set; }
    public virtual Box Box { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public int ResultBoxId { get; set; }
    public virtual Box ResultBox { get; set; }
}
```

The key of this "HistoryEntries" table would be a multicolumn key: it consists the BoxId and the UserId:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryEntry>().HasKey(entry =>
            new
            {
                BoxId = entry.BoxId,
                UserId = entry.UserId
            });
```

However, I want to turn off the lazy loading and the proxy creation because I would use every query with eager loading.

How to rewrite my code in an "eager loading" style?

Comment: Is your question about how to map multicolumn keys? (Or: why does the composite key matter?)

Comment: Be careful with this. Eager loading can cause massive data transfers.

Comment: I think the massive data transfer can be avoidable with a reasonable data access logic. I've just read that eager loading could be dangerous too, I mean the "n+1 select problem".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Include` method to eager load the navigational properties.

```
var users = context.User.Include(u => u.HistoryEntries.Select(h => h.Box))
      .Where(/* */);
```

Comment: Also remove the `virtual` keyword from the Navigation Properties. This will throw null reference Exceptions when you forget to eager load the related objects.

Comment: Thanks for everyone! My question was about the proper way of entity property declarations in a multicolumn key case.
I've already know that if you want to lazy load an XXX property of type T, just put an XXXId property of int and a virtual XXX of type T.
But you can't use the virtual keyword if you want to turn off the proxy creation.
But you still need the "int" properties, because of the multiple keys!
So I ended up with removing the virtual keywords from everywhere but leaving the int properties, as Dabblernl wrote.
Maybe this will cause a problem in the future, but now it looks fine.